# How to add margin/padding between Images inside a ListView?

Tags: image, listview, flutter, dart

I have a List View full of Images. The image are placed one after another. Between them is no margin or padding but I need some space. Is there something like 
 in HTML? When I add padding to ListView nothing on the Images changes. 
Do I have to add the padding to each picture?

I have tried to add
    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0,),
to Expanded and to ListView. I have tried the same on the image.assets. 
Nothing worked for me.

```
     child: new ListView(
     children: [
     Image.asset('images/offers/Beardshave.jpg',
     height: 240.0,
     fit: BoxFit.fill,),
     Image.asset('images/offers/GelNails.jpg',

     height: 240.0,
     fit: BoxFit.fill,),
     Image.asset('images/offers/Getintouch.jpg',
     height: 240.0,
     fit: BoxFit.fill,),
     Image.asset('images/offers/HotStone.jpg',
        height: 240.0,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,),
     Image.asset('images/offers/Lavendel-oil.jpg',
        height: 240.0,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,),
     Image.asset('images/offers/Paarmassage.jpg',
        height: 240.0,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,)
    ],

    ),
    ),
```

Comment: Between each `Image.asset` use - `SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          )`

Comment: @anmol.majhail That's the correct way, you should write it as answer before someone does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to add padding to each image by wrapping the image with a Padding widget. 
Another solution would be adding space between imagen with a Widget like this:

```
[

  Image.asset('images/offers/Beardshave.jpg',
     height: 240.0,
     fit: BoxFit.fill,),
 SizedBox(height: 10,),
 Image.asset('images/offers/GelNails.jpg',


]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a component like ImageWithPadding and return a Padding widget with image.asset beeing his child.

Something like that:

```
ImageWithPadding() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Image.asset('images/offers/Paarmassage.jpg',
             height: 240.0,
             fit: BoxFit.fill,)

    )
```